# Using VideoView with basic authenticated URLs

Tags: android, android-videoview, basic-authentication

I'd like to know how to properly display video from an authenticated URL to VideoView. My code is functioning before Lollipop (5.0). Now, after compiling to APIs 21 and 22, the error occurs. I have tried compiling back to API 19 but the appcompat library I'm using break so many codes. Here's my sample code:

```
                Uri videoUri = Uri.parse("https://user:12345@sample.com/dir1/dir2/dir3/myVideo.mp4");
                vidAtt.setVideoURI(videoUri);
```

I already tried

```
vidAtt.setVideoURI(videoUri, headers);
```

but the minimum API is 21 while mine is API 16. I tried the generated URI and paste into the browser and it works. It just doesn't work in the device. I also tried passing the URI as an intent so that it can open the video link externally, whether using the stock video player or a third part one. It didn't work too.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the setVideoURI-Method which is only available with Reflection:

```
Method setVideoURIMethod = videoview.getClass().getMethod("setVideoURI", Uri.class, Map.class);
setVideoURIMethod.invoke(videoview, Uri.parse(url), /*HashMap<String, String>*/ basicAuthentication;
```

Replace basicAuthentication with your Basic Authentication Header.

Comment: This only works in API 21 and above. It does not work below API 21 like 16 (4.1.1) or 17 (4.2.2).

Comment: I already used it on APIs below 21. The method is just not visible in lower API version. But using Reflection will do the job.

Comment: You're right. I tried other device and emulator and it works.

Comment: My mistake. I tried that code block before and it doesn't work. It's because I still put setVideoURI() on top of it. I removed it and now it works.

Comment: @PhilippE did you know for how many old versions is this working?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this

```
try {
    VideoView.setVideoPath("https://user:12345@sample.com/dir1/dir2/dir3/myVideo.mp4"); 
    } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
   }
   VideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
    // Close the progress bar and play the video
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        //             

        VideoView.start();

    }
   });
```

Comment: I tried that and nothing happens. The same error occurs.